# Magento removed orders from table sales_flat_order

Tags: magento, orders

Magento sent a customer a receipt with the order number but I cannot find that order number in Magento. I investigated that table sales_flat_order and noticed that the entity_id column is not sequential (an auto increment column) that indicates some records were deleted. Before I start doubting it's an intrusion, is there anything like that Magento does? I.E. removing orders from sales_flat_order ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a standard magento installation it is not possible to delete an order.
You can only do it by hand in the database or install an extension.